# TCP sender sends more data packets in between retransmissions

Tags: tcp

I am facing a problem related to the TCP retransmissions.

My Sender starts sending some data to receiver (which is not in the network after opening the connection), after sending 3 packets, it retransmits first packet 3 times (as per the retransmission timeouts)and start sending next packets.

Then it retransmits first packet again. I am not able to understand this behavior and want to know if there is some way I can disable this and force TCP to retransmit first packet and then close the connection if no ack is received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. It's a streaming protocol, not a datagram protocol.